# How to style parent based on pseudo-class of child?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I have a span containing an input tag, and I have declared an :after pseudo-element in the span for styling it.

```css
span::after {
  content: 'valid';
  color: green;
}

input:invalid {
  outline: 2px solid red;
}


/*
span::after that contains an input:invalid {
  content: 'invalid';
  color: red;
}
*/
```

```html
<span>
  <input type="number" min="2" />
</span>
```

I want to change the color of the pseudo-element anytime the input value is invalid.

Is there anyway to do that with pure CSS? Or do I have to use some JavaScript?

Comment: Could the span  (or some other element) go immediately after as you can then use :invalid + * {css settings here}

Comment: can you put some codes to reproduct your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Styling a parent element based on a child is only possible in CSS with the [The Relational Pseudo-class `:has()`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#relational) which is currently [only supported by safari](https://caniuse.com/css-has).

You would implement it like this:

```css
span:has(input:invalid)::after {
  color: red;
}
```

```css
span::after {
  content: 'valid';
  color: green;
}

input:invalid {
  outline: 2px solid red;
}

span:has(input:invalid)::after {
  content: 'invalid';
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <input type="number" min="2" />
</span>
```

For the time being, you would either have to

- Implement a [JavaScript polyfill](https://github.com/jplhomer/polyfill-css-has)
- Adapt your markup as suggested by A Haworth, so that the [next sibling selector](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) can be used instead.

Here is an example of how you could adapt your markup:

```css
span::after {
  content: 'valid';
  color: green;
}

input:invalid {
  outline: 2px solid red;
}

input:invalid+span::after {
  content: 'invalid';
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" min="2" />
<span></span>
```