# CSS: modifying style of another class on hover is not working

Tags: html, css, reactjs

So I have this table, which consists of some data. I want to show a tooltip whenever I hover on the row of the table. Hover is working on the row, but the visibility of the tooltip is not changing.
Here is what I have done so far:

```
<table id='aoi-table'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th colSpan={2}>Critical PS</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {cityData.map((item) => {
            return (
              <tr onClick={() => dispatch(addArea(item))}> //I want to hover here.
                <td>{item.name}</td>
                <td>
                  <div className='status'>
                    {(() => {
                      if (item.status === "Safe") {
                        return <Dot color='#24A148' className='status-dot' />;
                      }
                      if (item.status === "Observe") {
                        return <Dot color='#F1C21B' className='status-dot' />;
                      }
                      if (item.status === "Critical") {
                        return <Dot color='#DA1E28' className='status-dot' />;
                      }
                    })()}

                    <div className='status-line'>{item.status}</div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div className='aoi-critical-value-wrapper'>
                    {item.critical}
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  {(() => {
                    if (item.criticalValue > 0) {
                      return (
                        <div className='aoi-critical-value-positive'>
                          <UpArrowAlt className='icon-arrow' />
                          {item.criticalValue.toString()}
                        </div>
                      );
                    } else if (item.criticalValue < 0) {
                      return (
                        <div className='aoi-critical-value-negative'>
                          <DownArrowAlt className='icon-arrow' />
                          {item.criticalValue.toString().substring(1)}
                        </div>
                      );
                    } else {
                      return (
                        <div className='aoi-critical-value-neutral'>
                          {"-"}
                          {item.criticalValue}
                        </div>
                      );
                    }
                  })()}
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div className='tooltip-box'> //the tooltip div
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus,
          sit eligendi quae rem, exercitationem at aut modi ut fugiat, odio
          alias quaerat! Sed similique ut libero quos temporibus. Eaque, illum?
        </p>
        <p style={{ color: "#4589FF" }}>Learn more....</p>
      </div>
```

Table and tooltip styling so far:

```
#aoi-table {
  border-spacing: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
//styling of table headers
#aoi-table th {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #21272a;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
}
//styling of tabular data
#aoi-table td {
  padding: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
//when hover on table row inside table body
#aoi-table tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #343a3f;
}

#aoi-table tbody tr:hover td:nth-child(1) {
  border-left: 5px solid #0f62fe;
}
//tooltip styling
.tooltip-box {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% + 10px);
  left: 230px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d5358;
  width: 230px;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  text-align: justify;
}

//changing the style of tooltip while hovering on table row inside table body, as it is adjacent div used the ~ selector
#aoi-table tbody tr:hover ~ .tooltip-box {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

I have checked putting the both +,~ selectors and also without selectors, tooltip still not visible. Also tried putting the modifying part before the tooltip class, still it doesn't work. I think I may doing this wrong. Please need some help regarding this.

Comment: A snippet would be better... BTW it may be a [specifity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) problem

Comment: @Gurgolo I changed aoi-table into classname, using .aoi-table not working. Also tried changing the specification of tooltip-box too. Doesn't work either

Answer (score 2):

Currently your selector tries to select a .tooltip-box that is a sibling of tr:hover.
I think the problem is with trying to select an element based on an attributed child. In your case the child is also under a different element.  According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71991149/how-to-style-parent-based-on-pseudo-class-of-child), you can do

```
table:has(tr:hover) ~ .tooltip-box
```

But it will work only in Safari ([Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)) or with [JavaScript Polyfill library](https://github.com/jplhomer/polyfill-css-has).

You can just add some JS, and add a conditional classname to tooltip-box.

```
const [isTooltipToggled, setIsTooltipToggled] = useState(false)
...
<tr onClick={() => setIsTooltipToggled(!isTooltipToggled)}>
</tr>
```

And then

```
<div className={'tooltip-box' + (isTooltipToggled ? ' toggled' : '')}>
```

In the css file:

```
.tooltip-box.toggled{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Here's some info on conditional classnames: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/applying-classes-conditionally-react

:)

Comment: the react approach almost worked. But I want to hover on the table row and show the tooltip box. Problem is, hovering over react element is changing state is a pain. onMouseLeave, OnMouseEnter doesn't work properly.

Comment: Notice there's also onMouseOver and OnMouseOut. Try to give it a go.
[OnMouseEnter vs onMouseOver](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_mouseenter_mouseover) comparison
[onMouseLeave vs OnMouseOut](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_mouseleave_mouseout) comparison

Comment: Okay I will give it a try and get back.